# How do I iterate through an array inside a Raku hash?

Tags: arrays, json, hash, raku

This seems like a simple question, but Perl6/Raku isn't behaving as I'd expect.  I'm trying to create a reference to an array within a hash, but am not getting the expected behavior.  In Perl5, the answer would involve accessing the array by reference, but I don't see equivalent syntax for Perl6/Raku.

```
my $jsonstr = q:to/END/;
{
    "arr" : [
        "alpha","beta","delta","gamma"
    ]
}
END

my %json = from-json $jsonstr;
my @arr = %json{'arr'};
say "Arr length is " ~ @arr.elems; # Expect 4, get 1
say "Orig length is " ~ %json{'arr'}.elems; # Get expected value of 4
say "Arr[0] is " ~@arr[0].^name ~ " of length " ~ @arr[0].elems; # First index is array

say %json{'arr'}[0]; # Indexing into array in original location works as expected
say @arr[0][0]; # But when assigned, it needs an extra index

my @arr2 = @arr[0]; # Same issue in re-assignment here
say "Arr2[0]: " ~ @arr2[0] ~ ", length of " ~ @arr2.elems;
```

How do I get a new @arr variable to reference the nested array without this confusing extra [0] index layer?  Is this a bug, or am I missing something in my understanding of Raku's Array/ref handling?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you assign the value in the key `arr` to the Array `@arr` it takes the value in `%json{'arr'}` which is the Array Object `["alpha","beta","delta","gamma"]` and puts it into `@arr` so you get an Array of Array's with 1 item.

You've got a few options :

You can bind `@arr` to `%json{"arr"}` with `my @arr := %json{"arr"}`

Or you can pass the `%json{"arr"}` to a list with `my (@arr) = %json{"arr"}`

You have to remember in Raku Array's are Objects.

Comment: From a performance point of view, the `my @arr := %json<arr>` solution is best, as it doesn't need to copy any values, nor does it need to create any additional objects.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, after writing+posting my question, I answered my own question.

```
my @arr = %json{'arr'}.Array;
```

I don't quite understand why this is necessary, but it gives the desired behavior.

Comment: `%json{'arr'}` is a scalar (think, reference to an array). Calling the Array method is "dereferencing" the scalar, or more exactly, is putting the scalars content from its scalar container into a list container. You could also have written `%json{'arr'}.flat` or `|%json{'arr'}`, though I think the `Array` method is a bit faster in this case.

Comment: To elaborate. In Raku, Arrays and Lists do not flatten automatically, Hence `my @a = (1,2), (3,4)` will create an array of lists with two elements, not a array of ints with four.

Comment: Raku doesn't have any references, it only has immutable values and containers.  Your solution does the following: 1. coerce the `Array` object in the hash to an `Array`: this by itself is a noop, but more importantly, it loses the container in which the Array was stored in the hash.  Since the `Array` object is Iterable, it will copy its values into the `@arr` array, potentially doing a lot of unnecessary work for large arrays.